How to access the coordinates of vertices of a Qt3D QMesh?
I have an application which loads a wavefront (.obj) file to a QMesh, for which I need to access the coordinates of the vertices. There has got to be a way to access this data, but for the life of me, I can't find it. In examples found, vertex data is code-generated and contained within the PositionAttribute of a QGeometry, but I can't find an example of QGeometry being accessed from a QMesh.
End goal is to display the object with a color gradient, based on the relative z coordinate of vertices (I was thinking assigning color values to each vertex using QAttribute and adding to QGeometry, using QPerVertexColorMaterial, if that works all).
Here is the starting code. Apologies for the
import sys
import numpy as np
import struct
from PyQt6.QtCore import Qt, QByteArray
from PyQt6.QtGui import QColor, QVector3D
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QApplication
from PyQt6.Qt3DCore import QEntity, QGeometry, QAttribute, QBuffer, QTransform
from PyQt6.Qt3DExtras import Qt3DWindow, QPhongMaterial, QSphereMesh, QOrbitCameraController, QPerVertexColorMaterial
from PyQt6.Qt3DExtras import QDiffuseSpecularMaterial, QTextureMaterial, QNormalDiffuseMapMaterial, QDiffuseMapMaterial 
from PyQt6 import Qt3DRender
from PyQt6.Qt3DRender import QCamera, QGeometryRenderer, QMesh

# Load obj file into a QMesh
filepath = "C:/sample.obj"
mesh_object = Qt3DRender.QMesh()
mesh_object.setSource(QtCore.QUrl.fromLocalFile(filepath))
mesh_entity = QEntity(self.rootEntity)
mesh_entity.addComponent(self.mesh_object)

# Access vert data
# ---

# Assign a color attribute to each vertex
# ---

# Display in a 3DViewer
# ---


But a QMesh inherits from QGeometryRenderer - doesn't the latter have all the info you need? https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qt3drender-qgeometryrenderer.html
